# Reading CSV with float and Int in a column

Tags: python, csv, types, load, dtype

I am trying to load a csv file without converting the integer value (4950) into float (4950.0). The column has a mixture of both integer and float. I don't want the conversion because I need to create a Boolean column to check if the data in the column is float or not.

How do I go about loading the csv file to load the csv the way it was.

```
   final_collar['ELEV_FLOAT']=np.where(final_collar['ELEV'] ==float, True, False)
   final_collar.head(20)
```

Comment: there is a lot wrong here. For starters, you **don't want to have mixed types in a column**, that pretty much defeats the purpose of `numpy`/`pandas`. What you want is to test if the float *represents an integer number*. You could just do `final_collar['ELEV'] % 1 == 0`

Comment: Additionally, `np.where(final_collar['ELEV'] ==float, True, False)` would have never worked anyway, since `==float` would have been `False` for *everything* since *none* of the elements *equal the class `float`*